# Naming of Plot Commands in Sage

Tags: sage

I've started teaching myself sage and I'm a bit confused about the naming of some commands in graphics. The most basic command for graphics is perhaps plot with its variants polar_plot, contour_plot, etc. However, I've also seen some variants of plot that are obtained from it by adding postfixes to it, for instance, plot_vector_field.

Does anyone know the reason why some graphical commands belong to the first category (prefix_plot) and some to the second (plot_postfix)? I'm asking this because of there is a good reason for this, then it can help me remember the names more easily, and if there is no special reason this might be something to suggest for changes in future releases of sage as it is open source.

PS This is my first question on stackoverflow and I hope this is the right place for asking it, otherwise please feel free to move it anywhere that you feel it might belong.

Comment: Hi!  My guess is that sooner or later people will close this because it isn't really asking a programming question... you will also get more traction on ask.sagemath.org on this kind of question.  The short answer is that many early commands were named explicitly to mimic Mathematica command names (or, in some cases, Maple or Magma).  I think that the Sage team would be very open to creating aliases for `plot_foo==foo_plot`, though probably not in all cases.

Comment: @kcrisman Thanks for the suggestion. I've posted the question here http://ask.sagemath.org/question/26814/naming-of-plot-commands-in-sage/